# setAllowedOrigins("*") don't works on server. CORS configuration

Tags: java, angular, websocket, wildfly, stomp

I just finished [this tutorial](https://www.javaguides.net/2019/06/spring-boot-angular-8-websocket-example-tutorial.html) and it works on localhost (when I'm run backend on localhost:8080 and front on localhost:4200), but when I put my *.war file on server there is some CORS problem.

> Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at ‘http://mydomain.pl/ws/info?t=1591451334475’. (Reason: Credential is not supported if the CORS header ‘Access-Control-Allow-Origin’ is ‘*’)

I change this to allow but this not working :(

```java
@Override
public void registerStompEndpoints(StompEndpointRegistry registry) {
    registry.addEndpoint("/ws")
            .setAllowedOrigins("*")
            .withSockJS();
}
```

Could You hep me? I don't know what I'm doing wrong

Comment: Otherwise try `.setAllowedOrigins("http://localhost:4200")`

Answer (score 0):

The problem is wildfly. I just run jar on server without wildfly and the websocket works correctly. I'm probably don't configured something in wildfly.